# why org.apache.spark.sql.types.DecimalType's max precision value is 38 in SparkSQL?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am working with Apache Spark's SQL to process structural Bigdata. I came across usage of Spark SQL's datatypes specially DecimalType that support largest number to store than any other datatype from sparkSQL, but up to 38 precision even though according to documentation: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#data-types in that you can find: [image] and It internally use BigDecimal of Scala language which allow precision approx. 2^32. why it is so?

I need to achieve same functionality that provided by scala's BigDecimal with sparkSQL. can i get to know how i can achieve solution to this or any other way I can try out?

Comment: Yeah, why is a Spark DecimalType limited to a precision of 38?

I'm trying to read a MySQL table into Spark as a DataFrame.  The precision of the column in the MySQL table is declared as decimal(64,30), which results in an Exception.

Comment: @rake did you found a solution for this ?

Comment: No, nothing I would really call a "solution".  Don't remember exactly, but had to resort to some manual hack, such as reading a couple of columns as strings and throwing away enough digits so it would load as a Decimal. I was willing to live with a small number of bad values.

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood spark uses Java's BigDecimal.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

> A BigDecimal consists
>   of an arbitrary precision integer unscaled value and a 32-bit integer
>   scale. If zero or positive, the scale is the number of digits to the
>   right of the decimal point. If negative, the unscaled value of the
>   number is multiplied by ten to the power of the negation of the scale.
>   The value of the number represented by the BigDecimal is therefore
>   (unscaledValue × 10-scale).